SlackへのChatbot導入方法について
Slackワークスペースへチャットボットを導入したいですが、「〇〇が、共有されたチャンネルへの招待の送信や受信を実行する権限をリクエストしています。」と表示され、実行できません。この表示文が表示された場合、チャットボットを導入するにはどのような設定を行えば良いでしょうか？
<詳細>

自社でSlackのチャットボット(App/Integration)を開発しました。
開発したチャットボットはpublic distributionを有効にし、自社のワークスペース以外のワークスペースでも使用できるようにしました。
クライアント10社ほどに導入してもらいましたが、そのうち1社のみで「〇〇が、共有されたチャンネルへの招待の送信や受信を実行する権限をリクエストしています。(添付図参照)」と表示され、導入できていません。

添付図は問題のあったクライアントに共有してもらったものです。また、この操作を実施したユーザーはワークスペースのプライマリーオーナーでした。
Outhの機能を実装しており、問題がない場合はその認証承諾の画面が表示されます。


<試したこと>

導入を実施したユーザーのユーザータイプの確認。https://my.slack.com/account/workspace-settings#adminsから確認し、プライマリーオーナーと表示されました。

